# Looking for a Chrome web extension to alert when a TLS cert expires soon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, ssl

It would be great to have a Chrome extension (or Firefox, or Edgium, or Safari) that throws some kind of error starting a couple of weeks before a site's TLS Certificate expires.

Is there such a beast?

Is there another good and reasonably priced way to do this?

I ask because my test environment has some wildcard certs that have crept into various random servers. I know about the notification services, but the purpose here is to help find these places the wildcard certs have landed.

Answer (score -1):

A browser extension would not be an optimal solution, as it would require you to manually visit the website in question in order to receive the alert.

Most SSL/TLS certificate authorities will allow you to enroll in notifications to be alerted when a certificate is close to expiring.

If your authority does not provide this service, you can use the open-source tool [SSLPing](https://sslping.com/), which is free and will notify you about expiring certificates.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edit to my question.

Comment: So it sounds like you are looking for an SSL scanning tool, maybe something like this? https://xenarmor.com/network-ssl-certificate-scanner/